# jenkins grails build to tomcat javascript asset link issue

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap, tomcat, grails, jenkins

I have build war for grails project from jenkins to tomcat.But when I test app javascript assets are not linking correctly,So bootstrap menus are not working. But I did not faced such type of issue when I build using commanline.

Software Versions Which I have used:

- Grails : 2.4.2
- Grails asset-pipeline plugin version: v2.7.2
- git : 2.7.3
- jenkins : 1.653
- Java : jdk 8.x
- Jenkins Plugins Versions:
- Grails Plugin: 1.7
- Git Client: 1.19.6
- Git plugin : 2.4.2

[image: jenkins configuration for build]

Jenkins Console Log url: [jenkins console log](http://greenbuds.in/jenkinslog.txt)

Comment: Vasu, is the issue you are facing that the javascript assets are not being resolved when using Jenkins? Trying to get a little clearer explanation of the problem.

Comment: Yes @Nathan, the javascript assets are not being resolved while I am trying to build with jenkins.If I build through command line there is no such type of issue. I have used asset pipeline plugin(v 2.7.2)  in grails for compiling javascript and css files.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with the versions.